# Magento 2 product "packs"

Tags: magento2, attributes, stock, inventory

I want to implement a store with many small products that are usually bought in bulk (maybe 20-100 pieces at once). So I want to implement product "packs", i.e. a "pack of 10" alongside a "pack of 50". The packs should have different images and different pricing (i.e. a pack of 10 could cost 5$ and a pack of 50 only 20$).

So far I've been able to get close to my goal by using product attributes - I added a "size" attribute, and using a configurable product with product variations it's possible to achieve most of that behavior.

One issue remains with this approach though: I need to manage stock for the variations individually, while it'd be better to only keep track of one number (the total number of products in stock).

Is there any way to achieve this without coding that behavior myself? Any hints to get me started would be great.

Comment: Did you have any luck finding this for M2? I understand your need - creating packs of products (in our case there is 1 configurable with sizes as children). We want to create 3packs and 6packs of the same product.

Answer (score 0):

Use bundle products. You only need one simple product that actually has stock and represents one piece.

Then the 10-pack is a bundle that only has one option (the simple product) with fixed qty "10" and fixed price "$5". Same goes for other pack sizes.

The bundle itself is a container, similar to a configurable product, so it does not have stock, but can have own name, description, images and so on.

Make the bundles visible in catalog and the simple "not visible individually".

Comment: Bundle products seem to have negative "side effects" though when compared to configurable products. For one, the dropdown seemed like a good way to switch between "packs". That could be solved e.g. via related products though. What bothers me more is the additional click on "Customize and Add to Cart" that's necessary before a user can enter the quantity and add the product. I guess there isn't any quick way to get around that?

Comment: There is :) my suggestion does not involve any dropdown at all, each X-pack would be one bundle product. Use a single "checkbox" option and make it required. But if you want to have one page where you can select the pack size, it's more conplicated

Comment: Thanks. Yes this would work for a "1 size pack": how would this work exactly like the normal T-shirt where you select the PRODUCT. Then select the SIZE. Then select the QTY. In the example of the pack the only difference is that in the bacend a QTY of 6 is deducted (instead of 1). Also for Google Merchant https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/6324488?hl=en you would have to export the "pack multipier" -- actually the link above explains the  request workign quite well.

Comment: Also pricing is stored on the simple product level in M2 .... so there is 1 price only. Suppose we have a 2P, 4P and 6P ... ho would Magento then decide on the price to use